# How to reach my cubicles in Testchamber 11 of Chapter 8?

Tags: portal-2

So I made it into Chapter 8, but I got stuck into this room with lasers and Excursion Funnel.

[image]

I need to get my two cubicles on the left and right, but I can't seem to figure out how to reach them. I tried catapulting myself through the Excursion Funnel, but it just 'catches' you and I can't figure out how to get to the left one either.

Any hints on how to get to them?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

**Hint:** For the first cube, you don't use the faith plate (but it's target is helpful)

**Answer:**

> You're half way there in your picture, just turn around and put the blue portal on the faith plate target, which will fling you up.  Grab the cube, use it to shut down the funnel, then use the faith plate to fling you through where the funnel was and get the laser cube.

**The Whole Shebang:**

Here's right after your picture:

[image]

Then go place the cube to cut the laser beam and set up your second fling:

[image]

After using the faith plate to get to the prism cube, redirect it as shown to the other laser port

[image]

Go move the regular cube below the button, and go stand on the first lift.  Change the portals (disconnect the laser) to make the first lift rise.

[image]

Move the laser cube with portals to reactivate the funnel, and channel it to the box below the button to lower the second lift

[image]

Then just cut that portal, allowing the cube to fall, and escape.

Comment: It worked! You made Mrs Potato-head a happy Potato-head!